# Do VM's that thread require multiple instances for each thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, virtual-machine

I'm just starting to learn Python and have heard about the GIL and how it prevents "real" multithreading (by which I mean, allowing multiple threads to run on different cores simultaneously).

Now, hypothetically, were the GIL to be removed wouldn't each thread (now running on a different core) require a separate instance of the VM in order to execute?  Does the JVM have the same issue?

If so, is there any benefit to using threads in programs that are interpreted/execute on a VM vs separate processes (aside from the performance gain in using POSIX threads vs Processes - although I believe in Linux the difference isn't that great)?  Because having to have a separate instance of the VM for each thread seems like a lot of overhead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no requirement for separate "instances" of the VM. Why would there be? The problem with the GIL is it's one data structure which needs to be shared across all threads, and can't be safely accessed by multiple threads without locking. Basically the solution is to try to avoid that sort of thing :)

Many VMs will have *some* per-thread or per-core data structures (e.g. some JVMs can allocate memory from a thread-local heap, making the allocation really quick) but that's not the same as a whole separate VM instance per thread or core.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I thought you'd need a separate instance of the VM for each thread in order to actually execute the python/java code running on each thread (since they're not in machine code and so need to be executed by the VM and multiple instructions occurring simultaneously can't run on the same VM at once)

Comment: @Arash: Well, Python has rather more work to do than Java due to being more dynamic. Even if Java were still strictly interpreted, that interpreting could occur on multiple threads. However, most of the time, most Java code actually *is* running straight machine-code, which has been JIT-compiled from byte-code.

Comment: So, the VM code which is doing all the interpreting can itself be multithreaded, so code running in different threads that are to be executed by the VM are being executed by the different threads executing the actual VM (hopefully that makes sense)?

Comment: @Arash: Yes - but as I say, Java code doesn't actually tend to get interpreted much these days in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the GIL is just one of granularity. The GIL is a global lock that protects all the data structures of the Python interpreter, a solution would be to use finer-grained locks to protect those same data structures.

The situation is similar to that of the Linux kernel BKL (Big Kernel Lock), which was introduced in 2.0 to enable SMP. The BKL has been gradually substituted by finer-grained locks, and has finally went away very recently (2.6.39?).